# Is the FlexBox CSS library glitch-free enough for large websites like Facebook?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Is the FlexBox CSS library glitch-free enough to use on a large website? I have heard a while back (about a year) that is was extremely buggy and unusable, has anything changed?
I will be targeting desktop and mobile.

Comment: It’s not a library, AFAIK. Also, [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) is your best bet for questions like this.

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Answer (score -1):

You can check the compatibility of each CSS property at this site: [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/)